# Дай миллион! или Где взять истинно случайные числа?

Tags: случайные-числа

Нужен ровно миллион случайных чисел. В принципе, точность 1/256 меня устраивает, поэтому вопрос можно перефразировать: где взять миллион случайных байт? Не псевдослучайных, а именно случайных. Хотел скачать на random.org, там как раз выкладывают файлы объемом мегабайт каждый день. Мне нужен один, всего один такой файл, от любой даты. Мне этого хватит на всю жизнь (специфика программы такова, что между запусками последовательность может повторяться, главное чтобы "внутри" она была полностью случайная). А там не дают. :(

У меня даже такая мысль была. Берем первый попавшийся достаточно большой файл (iso-образ дистрибутива винды, например). Режем на миллион частей. Каждая часть получится около двух килобайт - вполне достаточно, ИМХО. Для каждой части высчитываем md5. Вот миллион случайных чисел, причем с точностью не 1/256, а 2^-128, что даже слишком круто. ;) Что думаете?

Comment: идете вот сюда https://www.random.org/bytes/ и в кол-ве вбиваете 16384, выбираете нужный формат. И повторяете процедуру 61 раз (будет 999424) или 62 раза (будет чуть больше миллиона).

В принципе, проксорив две последовательности между собой, можно получить вполне себе случайную последовательность, а это сильно сокращает кол-во обращений.

Comment: Была и такая мысль. Только червь сомнения гложет: полностью ли эти 16-килобайтные куски независимы друг от друга? А вдруг надо ждать сутки между скачиваниями, чтобы получить разные куски? По аналогии с мегабайтными кусками - https://www.random.org/files/
Или это уже паранойя? Весеннее обострение такое весеннее. %)

Comment: [/dev/random](https://ru.wikipedia.org/?title=/dev/random_%D0%B8_/dev/urandom) чем не подходит?

Comment: >где взять истинно случайные числа?

Все же мы прекрасно знаем, что рандом не такой уж и случайный.

Настоящий рандом можно получить, преобразовав волны космической радиации в числовое значение (с) какой-то серьёзный дядька на Рен-ТВ.

Comment: @VadimTukaev, чем сутки в этом плане отличаются от секунды?

> Для каждой части высчитываем md5. Вот миллион случайных чисел, причем с точностью не 1/256, а 2^-128

псевдослучайных

> где взять миллион случайных байт?

Создать на основе user input (голоса, дивжений мышкой и пр.). Можно просто микрофон в окне поставить и ловить шум улицы.

Comment: Шум улицы не случаен.

Comment: А чем вы измеряете вашу случайность ?

Comment: @Etki: И чем это, по существу, отличается от варианта с md5 iso-файла? Записываем шум с улицы, получается гигантский wav-файл, делим его на миллион кусочков и высчитываем от каждого md5. Так?

@ArchDemon: Очень просто. Вероятность каждого исхода (например, орел или решка) должна быть одинаковой, не должно быть корреляций.

Я все же склоняюсь к варианту использования файлов. Может быть, миллиона файлов (надо раздобыть клипарт какой-нибудь). Тот факт, что они получатся предсказуемыми, меня не волнует. Главное, что они друг от друга независимы. Мы ведь как бы не знаем предыдущие картинки. :)

Comment: @VadimTukaev, тем, что на диске вполне может быть повторяющаяся структура данных, например.

Comment: Ничто не случайно, а является следствием предыдущего состояния. Но смоделировать, просчитать и предсказать в большинстве случаев невозможно.

Шум улицы и байты в дистрибутиве могут иметь обусловленные спецификой характеристики: повторяющиеся нулевые байты в образе диска, примрно одинаковые пики от проезжающих примерно одинаковых машин. До true-белого шума обоим примерам далеко.

Может, как-то читать перемещения молекулы нагретого газа? =)

Comment: Я не думаю, что такой "неслучайности" надо бояться. Допустим, я возьму исходники ядра Linux, объединю в один гигантский текстовый файл и порежу на миллион примерно равных кусков. Очевидно, там будет очень много "похожих" кусков, но вряд ли они будут совпадать так, что 50% одного куска идентично 50% другого куска. Разве что таким куском будет текст лицензии GNU GPL. :)

А хэширование "размажет" все эти похожести. Ведь мне, по сути, надо "выжать" небольшое количество бит (от 8 и выше). Ну совпадут эти куски частично, ну и что? Хоть все BMP-файлы и имеют буквы BM в начале, а картинки-то разные..

Comment: @VadimTukaev, что произойдет, если эти числа будут недостаточно случайны?

Comment: Ну, ядерного взрыва не случится, если Вы об этом. Но хотелось бы все-таки "как можно более случайных чисел". Стандартный Random очень плох. Я рассматривал вариант генерировать миллион байт с помощью RNGCryptoServiceProvider. Это идеал по соотношению трудозатрат и "качества случайности". Надо было с самого начала на этом варианте и остановиться. Ох уж этот мой перфекционизм проклятый... Мешает жить.

Comment: @VadimTukaev, то есть у вас ни конкретной цели, ни метрик, по которым это можно определить исполнение необходимости, а просто странный и ничем не обеспеченный запрос?

Меня просто удивляет, как в одном месте для вас недостаточно хорош обычный рандом, рандом с рандом.орг, да вообще любой вариант, но вот выполнять md5, про равномерное распределение символов в которой никто ни слова не сказал - это норм. Ну и про эффект Даннинга-Крюгера, про физику и не разбирающихся в предмете людей - это верх.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Возьмите первый миллион байт числа Пи : )

**upd.** поможет [формула BBP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%91%D1%8D%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B0) и, к примеру, [код на C](http://habrahabr.ru/post/179829/).

upd.2. [про случайность цифр в Пи](http://www2.lbl.gov/Science-Articles/Archive/pi-random.html) и пр. фундаментальных константах.

Comment: Где взять? А лучше - как вычислить? Я и в гугле смотрел, и в Википедии - ничего достаточно простого не нашел. А идея красивая!

Comment: Формула Бэйли, Борвайна и Плаффа позволяет вычислить N-й **шестнадцатиричный** (как кстати!) знак числа Пи без вычисления предыдущих. А вот и [код на Си](http://habrahabr.ru/post/179829/).

Comment: @VadimTukaev, так если Вам не важно, что это будут *широкоизвестные* данные, то почему Вы не взяли файл (большой) с RANDOM.ORG (один из тех, мегабайтных, true random, что там делают каждый день и которых Вы сами говорили)???

Comment: @avp: С удовольствием бы взял, собственно это и была первая мысль. Так ведь не дают их. :( Вот сами попробовали бы скачать сначала...

Comment: Действительно, зачем-то хотят регистрации и т.п. и ничего "пиратского" за приемлемое время не нашел...

Answer (score 5):

1. В добавок к своему комментарию. Корреляционный анализ вы не выполняете, хотя утверждаете, что ваши числа недостаточно случайны.
2. Допустим, это не так, но ваш подход во взятии хэша куска большого файла самое плохое, что можно только представить. Тот же md5 имеет провалы в спектре.
3. Ни одним алгоритмом вы не построите истинно случайные числа.
4. Советую вам поискать специализированную литературу по этому вопросу. Я уверен, там вы точно найдете алгоритм, наиболее точно подходящий к вашей задаче (скорость + корреляция).

Comment: 1. Там, знаете ли, это и так очевидно из-за специфики алгоритма.
2. Не думаю, что провалы в спектре имеют большое значение, если превращать хэш md5 в число по принципу (float)md5 / float(2**128), т.е. в число от 0.0 до 0.999... Причем меня интересуют, по большому счету, только первые два знака после запятой.
3. Это очевидно. Но мне не нужны истинно случайные числа, а нужны числа, случайные как бы... относительно друг друга истинно случайные. Не знаю, как еще объяснить. Согласен, что слово "истинно" в вопросе слишком патетично звучит.
4. Скорость не важна, хоть сутки, мне же один раз обсчитать

Answer (score 3):

> Была и такая мысль. Только червь сомнения гложет: полностью ли эти 16-килобайтные куски независимы друг от друга? А вдруг надо ждать сутки между скачиваниями, чтобы получить разные куски?

Чтобы проверить это, нужно взять и протестить эти наборы. Для этого разработано куча тестов и методик.

В целом, откройте второй том Кнута и читайте всю третью главу. Там разбирается:

- Генерирование равномерно распределенных случайных чисел (включая много разных методик).
- Статистические критерии (для проверки, что последовательность действительно случайная).

Я сильно сомневаюсь, что на random.org или где-то ещё придумали что-то сильно лучше (ну кроме диода Шоттки с замером тепловых шумов) и их критерии проверки случайных чисел чем-то отличаются.

Также можно поискать книгу "Занимательные проекты на базе микроконтроллеров tinyAVR  Гадре Д.", где описано, как на базе диода Шоттки +avr контроллер сделать тот самый генератор. Ещё немного доработки - и он будет выдавать их в usb порт (а там их можно читать для своих нужд).

Comment: @VadimTukaev, а в самом деле, раз на https://www.random.org/   пишут:

    RANDOM.ORG offers true random numbers .... The randomness comes from atmospheric noise...

значит эти пресловутые 16-килобайтные куски будут независимы друг от друга.

Пожалуй, такой способ окажется быстрее, чем использование /dev/random, поскольку в `man 4 random` явно указывают, что эти данные не стоит читать слишком часто.

Comment: Возможно, я бы этим все озаботился, если бы случайные числа нужны были постоянно. Как я уже говорил, они нужны один раз и навсегда...

Comment: Тем более. Один раз собрали в кучку -- и все.

Answer (score 2):

Возьми сделай массив записей по порядку, а потом его "размешай"([php](https://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)), можешь кусками брать и вставлять в бд.

Вот тебе и миллион случайных чисел.

Comment: Лолшто? http://habrahabr.ru/post/137864/

Comment: Лол, не тупи. Возьми миллион записей по порядку и перемешай их просто.

Comment: Каких записей? По какому порядку? В какую БД? Вы о чем вообще?

Вы вопрос читали вообще? Такое складывается впечатление, что Вы, сообразительный Вы наш, тихо сами с собой ведете беседу...

Особенно забавляет словечко "просто". Тут люди обсуждают, а ему просто. Вспоминается одна дура с гуманитарным образованием, которая, узнав, что физики не могут поймать нейтрино, сказала: ну это же так просто, надо просто сделать штуку, у которой есть дно. Она искренне думала, что физики, многие из которых - нобелевские лауреаты, все это время пытались поймать нейтрино в "штуку" без дна. https://clck.ru/8akL

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, тут происходит подмена понятий.

*Случайное число* - это число, появление которого невозможно предсказать (угадать возможно).

*Уникальное число* - это число из последовательности, в которой нету повторяющихся чисел, их порядок может быть упорядочен.

Comment: Это Вы путаете случайность и непредсказуемость. Как я уже упоминал, в моей программе главное - случайность "внутри" миллиона чисел, сам миллион может быть один и тот же, т.е. абсолютно предсказуем. Когда-то, в советские времена, даже печатались справочники с длинными рядами случайных чисел для экспериментов... Куда уж предсказуемее...

Answer (score 0):

Как насчёт чтения из `/dev/random`?

https://ru.wikipedia.org/?title=/dev/random_%D0%B8_/dev/urandom

Comment: `/dev/random` - это генератор псевдослучайных чисел, а не истинно случайных чисел.

Comment: @PashaPash, насколько мне известно, числа там случайные, а не псевдослучайные. Википедия говорит то же самое: "Они предоставляют интерфейс к системному генератору случайных чисел, который выводит шумы из драйверов устройств и других источников в «хаотичный» пул (англ. entropy pool)."

Comment: А английская википедия говорит In Unix-like operating systems, /dev/random is a special file that serves as a blocking *pseudorandom* number generator. It allows access to environmental noise collected from device drivers and other sources. Шум от драйверов еще не гарантирует истинной случайности. Истинно случайные числа требуют железного генератора (**/dev/hwrng**). Которого в обычной десктопной системе скорее всего не будет.

Comment: @PashaPash Похоже, действительно так... Неожиданно.